# How can I clone a contract (using Openzeppelin 'clones') which contains a chainlink vrfCoordinator address in it's constructor?

Tags: chainlink, openzeppelin-contracts, solidity-0.8.x, proxy-contracts, clone

I'm trying to clone a Lottery contract which contains Chainlink VRF Coordinator address as part of the contructor. This is the constructor of the main contract which I'd like to clone:

```
    constructor(
    address vrfCoordinatorV2, //contract
    // uint256 entranceFee,
    bytes32 gasLane,
    uint64 subscriptionId,
    uint32 callbackGasLimit
) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
    // i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
    i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
    i_gasLane = gasLane;
    i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
    s_raffleState = RaffleState.CLOSED;
    s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
    contractOwner = payable(msg.sender);
}
```

Here is the code for my 'Clone' contract for which I am getting an error:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

    import './Raffle.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/KeeperCompatible.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";





contract RaffleFactory is Clones {
    Raffle[] public raffleArray;
    address public raffleImplementation;

    function createRaffle() public {
        address clone = Clones.clone(raffleImplementation);
        Raffle(clone).initialize(address vrfCoordinatorV2, bytes32 gasLane, uint64 subscriptionId, uint32 callbackGasLimit);
        return clone;
        raffleArray.push(clone);
    }
}
```

The error seems to be with initialising the vrfCoordinatorV2 address. I would like to create a clone factory contract which others can use to clone cheap instances of my main contract.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the error you are seeing? For one you should not `return clone;` before `raffleArray.push(clone);` and your method has no return value defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello [ethereumboy](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/107639/ethereumboy)

You need to define the data for all of these parameters:

- address vrfCoordinatorV2
- bytes32 gasLane (or keyHash)
- uint64 subscriptionId
- uint32 callbackGasLimit

Take a look on this example extracted from the
[VRF documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/examples/get-a-random-number/#analyzing-the-contract)

```
  // Goerli coordinator. For other networks,
  // see https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/#configurations
  address vrfCoordinator = 0x2Ca8E0C643bDe4C2E08ab1fA0da3401AdAD7734D;

  // The gas lane to use, which specifies the maximum gas price to bump to.
  // For a list of available gas lanes on each network,
  // see https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/#configurations
  bytes32 keyHash = 0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15;

  // Depends on the number of requested values that you want sent to the
  // fulfillRandomWords() function. Storing each word costs about 20,000 gas,
  // so 100,000 is a safe default for this example contract. Test and adjust
  // this limit based on the network that you select, the size of the request,
  // and the processing of the callback request in the fulfillRandomWords()
  // function.
  uint32 callbackGasLimit = 100000;
```

In order to use VRF, you need to create or already have a `subscriptionId`

Like was explained in [subscriptions](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/introduction/#subscriptions)

You are creating a Raffle Factory, so for each raffle that you create, you need to add it to your subscription, [programmatically](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/examples/programmatic-subscription/)